# How to get selected text in multiple text widget in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

i am trying to write little python tkinter app that show selected text (with mouse) another label. But i'm having problems with multiple text widget. How do i know which text widget i use? There are 10 text widget and when i select a text from any widget it should show the label. I'm using python 3.4.2 on windows 7. Thanks a lot.

```
#! python3
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

from tkinter import *

class omniAnaliz(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.screen()

    def screen(self):
        self.t1 = Text(self, height=1, width=50)
        self.t1.pack(side='top')
        self.t1.insert(END, '1D D6 F8 F0 C3 08 04 00 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69')
        self.t1.configure(state="disabled")

        self.t2 = Text(self, height=1, width=50)
        self.t2.pack(side='top')
        self.t2.insert(END, '30 F0 F8 D6 1D 64 64 01 00 71 1D 9F 00 1D 9F 00')
        self.t2.configure(state="disabled")

        # More text widget

        self.l1 = Label(self)
        self.l1.pack(side='top')

        self.t1.bind("<Button-3>", self.hex2dec)
        self.t2.bind("<Button-3>", self.hex2dec)

    def hex2dec(self, event):
        self.l1.config(text=self.t1.get(SEL_FIRST, SEL_LAST))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    omniAnaliz(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So to make thinkgs clear. You have a number of 10 Text widgets, and you want to get the label of a widget currently being used?

Comment: @Marcin, My main goal is to show selected data to the screen. No matter which widget is used. There are 10 data entry but one data output. Data entry is hex data. When i select one of hex data with mouse the program will convert hex to decimal and show result to the screen. Sorry my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you store each widget's Tkinter ID in a list and pass the offset for it to the function.  I prefer a StringVar to set() for the label, but that is personal preference.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

class omniAnaliz(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.text_vars=[]  ## text widget id's
        self.screen()

    def screen(self):
        ctr=0
        for txt in ['1D D6 F8 F0 C3 08 04 00 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69',
                '30 F0 F8 D6 1D 64 64 01 00 71 1D 9F 00 1D 9F 00',
                'a, b, c, 1, 2, 4']:
            t = Text(self, height=1, width=50)
            t.pack(side="bottom")
            t.insert(END, txt)
            t.configure(state="disabled")
            t.bind("<Button-3>", partial(self.hex2dec, ctr))
            ## first ID is item[0], 2nd text widget is item[1], etc.
            self.text_vars.append(t)
            ctr += 1

        self.label_text=StringVar()
        self.label_text.set("Nothing yet")
        self.l1 = Label(self, textvariable=self.label_text)
        self.l1.pack(side='top')

    def hex2dec(self, widget_num, event):
        this_text_widget=self.text_vars[widget_num]
        self.label_text.set(this_text_widget.get(SEL_FIRST, SEL_LAST))

root = Tk()
omniAnaliz(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Nice use of partial. Just for completeness, you could also bind to lambda, e.g. `lambda e, ctrr=ctr: self.hex2dec(ctrr, e)`

Comment: Guido wanted to remove lambda, map, and reduce from Python 3 but was convinced that it should be left in, in part for easier conversion, so I made the change to partial just in case.  I think partial also follows the explicit is better maxim.

Comment: Nice use of partial, but not really necessary since the widget that triggered the event is passed with the event object. `t.bind("<Button-3>", self.hex2dec)` and `this_text_widget=event.widget` works just as well.